# SVN with Android Studio MAC : ISSUE

Tags: android, macos, svn, android-studio

I am not able to connect/setup my svn with Android Studio on MAC.

Steps followed:
1. Open Project
2. VCS-->Import into Version Control-->Share Project(Subversion)
3. Add svn repository URL
4. Defined shared target-->Share
5. Select 1.7 format-->OK
6. Add username and password-->OK
7. Receive error Error:svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '......'

Tried to connect with command line and svn client
Got error: svn: E120107: Error running context: The proxy server returned an error while setting up the SSL tunnel.

Under network settings I have added my proxy settings.
Also in Android Studios, under HTTP Proxy, proxy settings are saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in servers file under ~/.subversion folder somehow proxy was set under the global section which was interfering the Android Studio settings for svn and svn cmdline.

After commenting the settings under global using "nano" command I was able to access svn repository.